# How do I run a frequency response analysis on a speaker cross-over circuit using Micro-Cap 12?

Tags: analog, simulation, passive-filter

I've got a simple speaker cross-over network drawn in Micro-Cap 12, I'm using a resistor in series with an inductor to represent the speaker, I've got a sine source as a voltage source to the circuit. The circuit has a few inductors, resistors and capacitors.

My primary question is - what sort of analysis do I want to run? AC, transient AC, Dynamic AC? And do I have the right "source" (a sine source?)? How do I know where Micro-cap is inserting the "input" signal?  I assume that the sine source is necessary for the analysis?  I've labelled some nodes or conductors as "in" and "out" but again I have no idea if Micro-cap is actually looking for and using them in the analysis.

[image: speaker crossover circuit]

I can run an AC analysis with appropriate audio frequency range and I get what looks like a believable band-pass output, but again I'm not sure that I have the analysis defined correctly, I would like to know how to define the operation of the sine source but I don't really see any way to do that.

Comment: Schematic is ok. You can do an AC analysis on the "out" pin by doing v(out). It will be done with V1 implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This analysis works with sine (or other) sources.
No need to adjust the parameters of this source.
Change "frequency range" with your needs (Higher, lower frequency).
Click right on "X range" button to change to "Autoalways" ...
And change the "Y range" directly with your need.

[image]

[image]